# How to handle huge file in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, memory-management, azure-blob-storage, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

in the last months I've been working on an exportation project, basically the application needs to get files from blob storage, unify the files in a single file, compress into a zip and upload it in blob storage. I fragmentated the process in steps. The performance is very good and the entire process is working, but when I export a lot of files, the last step crashes (beacuse my environment only have 15gb of memory and the file is bigger than that). Any ideas?

A little description of the final step and the codes:

1. Get all reated files from blob and storage them into a dictionary with the path and the byte[] of the file

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> DownloadManyAsync(Guid exportId)
{
    var tasks = new Queue<Task>();
    var files = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte[]>();

    var container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("");
    var blobs = container.GetBlobs(prefix: "");
    var options = BlobStorageTools.GetOptions();


    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        tasks.Enqueue(DownloadAndEnlist(container.GetBlobClient(blob.Name), files, options, exportId));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return files.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                              x => x.Value, 
                              files.Comparer);
}

public async Task DownloadAndEnlist(BlobClient blob, ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte[]> files, StorageTransferOptions options, Guid exportId)
{
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    await blob.DownloadToAsync(memoryStream, default, options);

    files.TryAdd(blob.Name, memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

2. Create a zip archive and write the bytes into it

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryTributary();

using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    for (int i = files.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var file = files.ElementAt(i);

        var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Key, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

        using var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open();

        zipStream.Write(file.Value, 0, file.Value.Length);

        files.Remove(file.Key);
    }
}
```

3. Saves the zip file into blob

```
public async Task<string> SaveExport(string fileName, Stream file)
{
    var cloudBlockBlob = _blobClient.GetContainerReference("").GetBlockBlobReference($"{fileName}.zip");

    BlockingCollection<string> blockList = new();
    Queue<Task> tasks = new();

    int bytesRead;
    int blockNumber = 0;


    if (file.Position != 0) file.Position = 0;

    do
    {
        blockNumber++;
        string blockId = $"{blockNumber:000000000}";
        string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8000000];
        bytesRead = await file.ReadAsync(buffer);

        tasks.Enqueue(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead) { Position = 0 }, null);

            blockList.Add(base64BlockId);
        }));
        
    } while (bytesRead == 8000000);

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockList);

    return cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString();
}
```

I thought in use az functions, but functions have 15gb memory limitation, i would have the same issue.

Comment: Are you running on VMs or as a managed web app? If you're running your application on a VM you could use Azure Premium Files as an intermediate staging area rather than holding them in RAM.

Comment: If you are using managed web applications another approach would be to subclass `Stream` to work with Azure Blobs and provide that stream to the zip export methods. It is tricky but doable.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion it runs on aks container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/) helped me a lot. Basically i used BlobStream to write my zip directly in storage, so the memory usage was very low. I hope this may help some future developers with the same issue.

The new code:

```
using (var zipFileStream = await _shareExportStorage.OpenZipFileStreamAsync(filename))
{
    using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(zipFileStream) {IsStreamOwner = false})
    {
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(4);

        foreach (var file in filesListTask.Result)
        {
            var properties = await _exportFilesStorage.GetBlobProperties(file);

            var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file)
            {
                Size = properties.ContentLength
            };

            zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
            await _exportFilesStorage.DownloadOneToStreamAsync(zipOutputStream, file);
            zipOutputStream.CloseEntry();
        }
    }
}

public async Task<Stream> OpenZipFileStreamAsync(string fileName)
{
    var zipBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(_configuration["AzureBlobStorage:ConnectionString"], "", fileName);

    return await zipBlobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, options: new BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions
    {
        HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/zip"
        }
    });
}

public async Task DownloadOneToStreamAsync(Stream destination, string blobName)
{
    var container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("");

    var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(destination, new BlobDownloadToOptions 
    { 
        TransferOptions = BlobStorageTools.GetOptions()
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice! so you download the blob directly to the entry in the zip file. yeah, that would keep the memory usage very low.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you have use a stream that is not in memory, like creating de zip file in disk. But I guess you don´t want to do that, so you can just create your zip file directly in the blob.

It is something like

```
using (var blobStream = await blob.OpenWriteAsync())
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(blobStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
}
```

On another topic. You may want to use RecyclableMemoryStreamManager to get the memory streams in your code so you can re-use the streams allocated before.

It is very easy to use, just create an instance of RecyclableMemoryStreamManager, and then get the streams from it.

```
private static readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager manager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();

using (var ms= manager.GetStream())
```

https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream

(Edited)

Oh! I haven´t noticed you download ALL streams before doing the zip thing. That means you need memory for all of them at the same time.

You may want to download some, then zip, then repeat.

Or maybe use ConcurrentQueue, and have a process that download and put the stream on the queue, and another process that takes the stream and zip it. To do this, you will need some kind of flag that says "Nothing else to download, once you empty the queue, you are done".

The idea is that you release the memory of the already zipped blobs.
If you do this, apply the ReciclableMemoryStream, and also write directly to the blob (or in local disk), you will reduce the amount of memory used by your process by a huge amount. And it will also increase the speed.

Comment: Wow that looks way easier than it used to be.

Comment: It's a nice suggestion, but I need only one zip file, if there is a way to append new files into a zipped one, it would be greatful.

Comment: it does, you just need to keep adding the files to the zip without closing it. it works like a "normal" zip stream.

Comment: really?? can you please send me some docs or example? my problem is keep the files in memory, write zip in batches will work fine to me

Comment: sorry, just came back, i see you find an example, and even more optimal. good job!